# JavaFx:How to use focused property?

Tags: javafx, focus

I have two TextFields `QntMatr` refers to Quantity of matter and  `UniteMatr` refers to Unit of quantity.I need when the user put cursor on `QntMatr` or `UniteMatr`,the Button `addMatrButton`should be disable ,and it will enabled when QntMatr and UnitrMatr are not empty both of them.I tried binding between `UniteMatr` and  `QntMatr` and  but i did not know the exactly method.

**Code**

```
 QntMatr.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    if (QntMatr.getText().isEmpty() && UniteMatr.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        AddMatrButton.setDisable(true);

                    } else {
                        AddMatrButton.setDisable(false);

                    }

                }

            }
        });
        UniteMatr.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    if (QntMatr.getText().isEmpty() && UniteMatr.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        AddMatrButton.setDisable(true);

                    } else {
                        AddMatrButton.setDisable(false);

                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: What happens, if the one of the `TextField`s is focused but both `TextField`s are non-empty? To me it seems to be bad user experience for the user to need to focus some other control in order for the `Button` to become enabled...

Comment: No, `QntMatr` and `UnitMatr` are optional fields.User can not add a quantity and leave unit empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a button disabled depending on a TextField content ( true if is empty , false otherwise ) then you should bind the Button's disableProperty with the TextField's textProperty. Here is an example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestClass extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        HBox box = new HBox(10);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TextField field = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("OK");

        button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(field.textProperty()));

        box.getChildren().addAll(field, button);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box));

        stage.show();
    }

}
```

If you want to make something more complex binding example in order to check if the field is focused of not you could do something like this :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestClass extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        HBox box = new HBox(10);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TextField field = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("OK");

        button.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {
            {
                bind(field.textProperty());
                bind(field.focusedProperty());
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean computeValue() {

                // you can check if the field is focused
                // of if it's content is empty etc.
                return field.getText().isEmpty();

            }

        });

        box.getChildren().addAll(field, button);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box));

        stage.show();
    }

}
```